# Doctrine says a field doesn't exist when it does - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity:

```
...

class UserRole extends Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_role_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
```

But when I try to use user_role_id in a doctrine query I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 42 near 'user_role_id': Error: Class
>   MyApp\Model\UserRole has no field or association named user_role_id

The query I am using is this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT r FROM Model:UserRole AS r WHERE r.user_role_id IN (:roles)')
    ->setParameter('roles', array_values($roles));
```

I've definitely got a user_role_id field as I can see it in phpMyAdmin.

Does anyone have any idea why doctrine is not recognising it?

Comment: This is doctrine and you want to write a DQL not a SQL, and you need to use the field names as defined in entities not the column names; so in your query just use `r.id` instead of `r.user_role_id`

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. I thought the SQL column names needed to be used. Cheers

Comment: No problem; I provide it as answer with a link to DQL documentation hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doctrine and you want to write a DQL not a SQL, and you need to use the field names as defined in entities not the column names.
So in your query just use `r.id` instead of `r.user_role_id`

Take a look at [DQL in Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)